# sound cloud like web page structure in playing audio

Tags: jakarta-ee, iframe, soundcloud, apache-tiles

as you start playing audio in [soundcloud](https://soundcloud.com/) you can see it playing in the header, and when you try to move/redirect to other pages the song continues to play in the header. can it be done by using `apache tiles` in `java ee`? or should i just use `iframe` for the body of the page or should just use ajax for the content of the body and dynamically add the element with the result of ajax. how can i redirect the body of the page without interrupting the audio player?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Soundcloud.com is a JavaScript [single page application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application).

I am guessing that your question is: **how to keep audio playing and change page content**. I am also guessing that you want **the URL to change when the page content updates**.

We use JavaScript and lousely do the following:

- have a wrapper object to control audio playback
- use HTML5 History API to react to the address change
- on address change, update content of the page

We use MVC, particularly Backbone. Because of this, instead of using History API directly, we rely on `Backbone.Router`. We also extended `Backbone.View` to build a type called `Layout`.

So when `Backbone.Router` triggers a route change event, appropriate `Layout` is initialised with the right params from the URL.

All of this time, `AudioManager` object can be interacted with to toggle and control playback.

I hope this helps with the direction of your research.

There are a couple of talks that explain how we built soundcloud.com, but perhaps it'd be a good idea to learn about general concept of JavaScript SPAs and MVC in order to understand that material:

- https://developers.soundcloud.com/blog/building-the-next-soundcloud
- http://spadgos.github.io/sfjs-next-soundcloud/

Comment: thanks @gyryzzly this answers all of my questions with soundcloud. i guess i should start reading about SPA, i've used MVC already with my web apps since it is recommended to be that way.